# Get Error when I change the time from 2019 to 2018 to get data from Metatrader

Tags: python, pandas, metatrader5

I using MetaTrader and Pandas Libraries to Get Forex Prices and Store to csv file.
When I set the from year to 2019 and after (2020,2021) everything is fine. But when I Set to 2018 or older year I get error from Panda. it seems when data is going to huge this is happening.
My code is:

```
def Get_Date_from_to(PAIR , TF , Location):
    timezone = pytz.timezone("Etc/UTC")
    year = datetime.now().year
    month = datetime.now().month
    day = datetime.now().day
    hour = datetime.now().hour
    minute = datetime.now().minute
    second = datetime.now().second
    if not mt5.initialize():
        print("initialize() failed, error code =",mt5.last_error())
        quit()
    date_from = datetime(2018, 1 , 1 , tzinfo=timezone)
    date_to = datetime(year,month,day,hour, minute, second , tzinfo=timezone)
    rates = mt5.copy_rates_range(PAIR, TF, date_from, date_to)
    # create DataFrame out of the obtained data
    rates_frame = pd.DataFrame(rates)
    # convert time in seconds into the 'datetime' format
    rates_frame['time']=pd.to_datetime(rates_frame['time'], unit='s')
    rates_frame.to_csv(Location)
```

and I Get this error:

```
rates_frame['time']=pd.to_datetime(rates_frame['time'], unit='s')
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'time'
```

Comment: There is no column `time`, what's the result of `print(rates_frame.columns.values)`?

Comment: [] when I use 2018 / ['time' 'open' 'high' 'low' 'close' 'tick_volume' 'spread' 'real_volume'] when I use 2019

Comment: `mt5.copy_rates_range()` seems not creating dataframe for 2018, what is `mt5`?

Comment: import MetaTrader5 as mt5
https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5/mt5copyratesrange_py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I increase **max bars in chart** to 100000 in Meta Trader and everything is fine now.

MetaTrader > Option > charts > max bars in chart